# CoreData: Fetching Children of Parent

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I have a CoreData model with a parent that contains many one-to-many relationships.  There is only one MenuList, but each child menu contains numerous entries.

```
MenuList
-------
WineMenu (one-to many relationship)
BeerMenu (one-to many relationship)
FoodMenu (one-to many relationship)
```

Is it possible to access the children menus directly from the parent?

I am obtaining the MenuList like this:

```
NSArray *theMenuList = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

There is only one object in theMenuList.  I am unable to do this:

```
theMenuList.wineMenu.wineName
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Is entering the entry through the submenu e.g. `menuList.wineMenu.entry` not good enough?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are sure you'll always only have one instance of MenuList in your database you could simply take the one single object from the returned array and use that.

```
NSArray *menuLists = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
MenuList *theMenuList = [menuLists lastObject];
NSLog(@"Wine name: %@", theMenuList.wineMenu.wineName);
```

Comment: I've tried that but am unable to access any WineMenu entities.

Comment: Does MenuList have a relation called wineMenu and did you define a [`NSManagedObject`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html) subclass with the properties?

Comment: Yes, the relationship between MenuList and WineMenu is setup.  What do you mean by defining a NSManagedObject subclass with the properties?

Comment: I mean [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdManagedObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003397-SW1). You have to declare the properties yourself. Otherwise you have to use `[[theMenuList wineMenu] wineName]` or `[[theMenuList valueForKey:@"wineMenu"] valueForKey:@"wineName"]`.